# Delegate is still nil

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, segue

I am passing user data from a view controller called `CreateNewAccount` to another view controller called `ThanksForJoining`. For some reason my delegate is `nil`. I am using a segue in order to set my `vc.delegate` to `self` (`= self`) and the segue identifier "thanksForJoining" refers to the segue that connects `CreateNewAccount` to `ThanksForJoining` on the storyboard. Somehow though, the delegate remains `nil`.

CreateNewAccount:

```
import UIKit

protocol UserInfoDelegate {
   func sendUserInfo(firstName: String, lastName: String, username: String, password: String)
}

class CreateNewAccount: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var FNInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var LNInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordInput: UITextField!

    var infoDelegate: UserInfoDelegate?

    @IBAction func sendInfo(_ sender: Any) {
        if(infoDelegate != nil){
            if(FNInput.text != nil && LNInput.text != nil && usernameInput.text != nil && passwordInput.text != nil){
                let firstName = FNInput.text
                let lastName = LNInput.text
                let username = usernameInput.text
                let password = passwordInput.text

                infoDelegate?.sendUserInfo(firstName: firstName!, lastName: lastName!, username: username!, password: password!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ThanksforJoining:

```
import UIKit

class ThanksForJoining: UIViewController, UserInfoDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var fName: UILabel!

    func sendUserInfo(firstName: String, lastName: String, username: String, password: String) {
        print(firstName)
        fName.text = firstName
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "thanksForJoining") {
            let createNewAccount: CreateNewAccount = segue.destination as! CreateNewAccount
            createNewAccount.infoDelegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Offtopic: in swift you normally don’t use ‘!= nil’. (It’s not Java thank god)

Comment: If it's true, _the segue identifier "thanksForJoining" refers to the segue that connects CreateNewAccount to ThanksForJoining_, then `prepare(for:sender:)` for `"thanksForJoining"` is called in `CreateNewAccount`, not in `ThanksForJoining`. The VC `ThanksForJoining` should have a delegate and you may need to set it in  `prepare(for:sender:)` of `CreateNewAccount`.

Comment: @OOPer could you please elaborate? I think you may be on to something as I still have not gotten it to work, BUT I am just trying to create a one way connection between CreateNewAccount and ThanksForJoining so I am bit confused by what you mean when you say that the VC ThanksForJoining should have a delegate. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to confirm that:

- You connected `CreateNewAccount` to `ThanksForJoining` via a segue.

[image: ViewControllersConnected]

- The segue's Identifier is set to `thanksForJoining` correctly
  (Be careful about the letter cases.)

[image: ConnectingSegue]

If any of the two is not true, you have lost a little time and I have lost my time to prepare for a big typhoon. Update your question to clarify what's happening and wait for someone to help you...

---

Assuming two things above, `prepare(for:sender:)` is called on the source view controller. You need to implement it in your `CreateNewAccount` class.

CreateNewAccount:

```
import UIKit

class CreateNewAccount: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordInput: UITextField!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "thanksForJoining" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ThanksForJoining
            if
                let firstName = firstNameInput.text, !firstName.isEmpty,
                let lastName = lastNameInput.text, !lastName.isEmpty,
                let username = usernameInput.text, !username.isEmpty,
                let password = passwordInput.text, !password.isEmpty
            {
                destinationVC.receiveUserInfo(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, username: username, password: password)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ThanksForJoining:

```
import UIKit

class ThanksForJoining: UIViewController {
    var firstName: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        firstNameLabel.text = firstName
    }

    func receiveUserInfo(firstName: String, lastName: String, username: String, password: String) {
        print(firstName)
        self.firstName = firstName
    }
}
```

Seems delegate pattern is sort of too much for your purpose and you just need to define a data passing method in the destination view controller `ThanksForJoining`.

I assume you have connected your segue from some button of your `CreateNewAccount`. If the segue is connected from the view controller (not from a button), the code above needs small modification.

But anyway, in your original code, the method `prepare(for:sender:)` in `ThanksForJoining` would never be called, so the delegate would never be set. Thus, *the delegate remains `nil`*.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a reference to the CreateNewAccount class in the class ThanksForJoining class. Then you need to activate the delegate by setting it equal to self in the ThanksForJoing class in viewDidLoad.

```
class ThanksForJoining: UIViewController, UserInfoDelegate {
    var createNewAccount: CreateNewAccount?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createNewAccount?.infoDelegate = self
    }

{
```

Then your delegate methods will work.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible issue is segue identifier mismatch in code and storyboard

In the story board, select the segue between two VCs

[image]

And then go the attributes inspector and set the ID "thanksForJoining" in "Identifier" field

[image]

**Some suggestions**

If your intention is to check whether user has entered all the fields before sending the data back, then this code will serve the purpose better

```
if (infoDelegate != nil) {
    if let firstName = FNInput.text, firstName.count>0,
        let lastName = LNInput.text, lastName.count>0,
        let username = usernameInput.text, username.count>0,
        let password = passwordInput.text, password.count>0 {

        infoDelegate?.sendUserInfo(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, username: username, password: password)
    }
}
```